# Setting up LDAP over SSL & startTLS using aws-ec2-Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap, ubuntu-16.04

I am Trying to setup LDAP environment using aws-ec2 Ubuntu 16.04 Instance with over SSL and startTLS.

Could you please help me out with the steps?

Thanks